# Including additional columns with COUNT DISTINCT query

Tags: sql, count, distinct

I have a table that has the following columns: Netting_Pool, Counterparty and Account.  My goal is to run a SQL query to show when there is a Netting_Pool with more than 1 Counterparty, and to show the Accounts linked to those Counterparties.

An example:

```
Netting_Pool   Counterparty   Account  

        1   -----  A -----   ASD
        1   -----  A -----   XYZ
        1   -----  B -----   DEF
        2   -----  C -----   YUI
        3   -----  D -----   TRE
        4   -----  E -----   DDW
        5   -----  F -----   QWE
```

I would like the query to have the following Return:

```
        1   -----  A   -----  ASD
        1   -----  A   -----  XYZ
        1   -----  B   -----  DEF
```

So far the closest I have come is the following:

```
SELECT netting_pool, count (distinct counterparty)  
FROM Table  
GROUP BY netting_pool  
HAVING count(distinct counterparty) > 1'
```

Which returns:

```
Netting_Pool, Count (distinct Counterparty)  

1             2
```

I have not been able to incorporate the Counterparty or Account values to my query and have it produce the results I want. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Add your DB tag:mysql,sql server,other?

Comment: Are you using Oracle?

Comment: I believe I am using Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is aggregating, so you are only going to be getting one row.  Another way to do this is with window/analytic functions, which are supported by most but not all databases.

Unfortunately, `count(distinct)` is not generally supported as a window function.  But you can work around this by looking at the maximum and minimum values:

```
select Netting_Pool, Counterparty, Account
from (select t.*,
             min(account) over (partition by Netting_Pool) as mina,
             max(account) over (partition by Netting_Pool) as maxa
      from table t
     ) t
where mina <> maxa;
```